# How can I rerender my redux state after triggering an action with hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-hooks

I'm trying to update a state from my Redux by triggering an action that calls out an API.

I have tried debugging by using a console log on actions and the reducer to see whether the states are changing.

The API returns an object and stores it into the reducer and it seems to work just fine but the Screen UI didn't re-render or update the reducer state.

I tried using useState React Hook function to test whether the issue comes from my component or the dispatch function and turns out the issue is from Redux dispatch hook.

In this case, when I press on my ToggleSwitch component, the action triggers the API and store the new value to the reducer. But the state on the UI side isn't updating.

Here's my code

reducer:

```
const light_list = (state: object = {}, action) => {
    if (action.type === C.FETCH_ALL_LIGHTS) {
        state = action.payload;
        return state;
    } else if (action.type === C.CHANGE_LIGHT_STATE) {
        _.merge(state[action.id].state, action.payload);
        return state;
    } else {
        return state;
    }
}
```

action:

```
export const UpdateLightState = (lampID, jsondata) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    const state = getState();
    const { id }: BridgePairedType = state.pairing_bridge;
    const bridge: ConfigurationTypes = state.bridge_list[id];

    const response = await axios({
        url: `http://${bridge.ipaddress}/api/${bridge.username}/lights/${lampID}/state`,
        method: 'PUT',
        data: jsondata
    });
    if (response && response.data) {
        var payload = {};
        response.data.map((data) => {
            let key = Object.keys(data.success)[0].substring(Object.keys(data.success)[0].lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
            let value = Object.values(data.success)[0];
            payload[key] = value;
        })
        dispatch({
            type: C.CHANGE_LIGHT_STATE,
            id: lampID,
            payload: payload
        })
    }
}
```

Screen UI:

```
function ControlBulbScreen() {
    const { colors } = theme;
    const lampID = useNavigationParam('lampID');

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const light: LightTypes = useSelector(state => state.light_list);
    const updatelight = useCallback((lampID: string, json: LightUpdateStates) => dispatch(UpdateLightState(lampID, json)), [dispatch]);

    const bordercolor = { borderColor: colors.white }

    return (
        <Block style={styles.container}>
            <Block flex={false} center row space="between" style={styles.header}>
                <Text h1 googlebold>{light[lampID].name}</Text>
                <ToggleSwitch
                    offColor="#DDDDDD"
                    onColor={theme.colors.secondary}
                    onToggle={() => updatelight(lampID, { on: !light[lampID].state.on })}
                    isOn={light[lampID].state.on}
                />
            </Block>
        </Block>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        paddingHorizontal: theme.sizes.base * 2,
        backgroundColor: theme.colors.background 
    },
    header: {
        marginTop: 40
    },
    textControl: {
        textAlign: 'left',
        fontSize: 16
    },
    controlrow: {
        marginTop: 20,
        marginBottom: 10
    },
    thumb: {
        width: 25,
        height: 25,
        borderRadius: 25,
        borderColor: 'white',
        borderWidth: 3,
        backgroundColor: theme.colors.secondary,
    },
    textInput: {
        height: 30,
        borderBottomWidth: .5,
        borderRadius: 0,
        borderWidth: 0,
        color : theme.colors.white,
        textAlign: 'left',
        paddingBottom: 10
    }
});

export default ControlBulbScreen;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the issue is in your reducer. You **should not mutate** your `state` directly. What I suggest is to create a new state instead what you need to *return in each case*.

The following statement will do the job for you: `const newState = {...state}`.

Try the following:

```
const light_list = (state: object = {}, action) => {
    if (action.type === C.FETCH_ALL_LIGHTS) {
        return action.payload;
    } else if (action.type === C.CHANGE_LIGHT_STATE) {
        const newState = {...state};
        _.merge(newState[action.id].state, action.payload);
        return newState;
    } else {
        return state;
    }
}
```

Read further about [Immutable Update Patterns](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns/) in the documentation.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for the detail explanation. It works perfectly now :D

Comment: Is it recommended to add a new state for all cases or just for updating/ delete state?

Comment: @FirmanJamal In those cases when you want to change the `state` only. If there is no change on the `state` it is enough to have `return state`.

Comment: What about inserting a new objects into the state?

Comment: @FirmanJamal If you have want add something new than you shouldn't mutate the original object. You should copy and add there your new object. I hope that clarifies.